# Swift enum type wrapper in generic functions

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I want to wrap the result of an asynchronous function response with an enum:

```
enum Result<T> {
  case Success(T)
  case Failure(Error)
}
```

The main idea is to determine with a `switch case .Success(let rep) case .Failure (let err) etc.` if the async function has succeeded or failed.

The problem is I need/want to put that result enum on a `Channel<T>`.
Doing something like

```
let ch = Chan<Result>()  // define a channel on which I can put a 'result'
// for example when fetching a user

if(success) put(ch, .Success(user)) //put .Success with user inside on the channel
else put(ch, .Error(error))
```

The problem is Swift doesn't let me put `Result`-enums on a `Chan<T>`.
Is it possible to put Enum values which has in the .Success a 'T'-generic struct/class embodied? That same enum could for example contain a .Failure with an error.

Is there a way to wrap a generic with an enum value type without violating The Great Laws of The Swift Type System?

PS:
The above is pseudocode, put is an alias for an operator `func <~<T>(l: Chan<T>, r: T)`, 
Chan is from github.com/tidwall/Safe/blob/master/Source/chan.swift

Comment: Please show how `put` and `Chan` are defined

Comment: The above is pseudocode, `put` is `func put<T>(l: Chan<T>, r: T)`, Chan is https://github.com/tidwall/Safe/blob/master/Source/chan.swift

Comment: @Seneca please add the asked details to the question, without those the question is unclear (definition of `Chan`, of `put`, errors you get from Swift, etc). We want to help you, but you also have to help us fully understand the question and it's context.